# $x^*Ax>0$ for all nonzero $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ implies positive minimum on sphere.

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that if $x^*Ax>0$ for all nonzero $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then $x^*Ax$ has a positive minimum on $S=\{x:|x|=1\}$ where $|x|=\sqrt{|x_1|^2+\cdots+|x_n|^2}$.

I know the idea for the real space: $S$ is compact since it is an inverse image of a point under norm function, which is continuous. Also the map $x^t Ax=\sum a_{ij}x_ix_j$ is continuous since it is a polynomial of coordinates, so it has a positive minimum on $S$.

But is it true for complex case? I actually don't know what is the topology on $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Suppose the topology is given by the norm $|x|$, i.e. by the metric $|x-y|$. Then $S$ will be compact, since $||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|$ implies the continuity of the norm. But why is the map $x^*Ax=\sum a_{ij}\bar{x_i}x_j$ is continuous? I want to use the coordinate argument but is it possible?

Comment: In a normed vector space, real or complex, compact=closed+bounded (Heine-Borel). In particular, the unit sphere is compact (you can also see this directly using the equivalence of norms and proving this for the $\ell^\infty$ norm). Now $x\longmapsto x^*Ax$ is continuous. For instance, the bilinear map $(x,y)\longmapsto x^*Ay$ is bounded, hence continuous. So your map is a fortiori continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\mathbb R^{2n}$ and $\mathbb C^n$ are pretty similar spaces, and $|x+iy|^2=\lVert(x,y)\rVert^2$.